# Elastic search sorting - Non Nested Elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use sort in elastic search. I tried nested sort suggested in
[ES - Nested Sorting Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#_nested_sorting_examples)

But later I found that my index is in the way, where the property is not of type "nested".

[image: Image - ES mapping]

So what's the best way to sort inner elements which is a non-nested type.

I'm looking to use sort in MDMGlobalData.City field

Comment: Did you try `MDMGlobalData.City` in sort param?

Comment: Please provide text version of your mappings code, since it can be easily copied and tested by us...Refrain from using image code whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

Okay I tried to replicate ur issue

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "MDMGlobalData": {
        "properties": {
          "City": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inserted docs with these

```
POST my_index/_doc
{
  "MDMGlobalData.City":  "Chennai"
  
}
POST my_index/_doc
{
  "MDMGlobalData.City":  "Bangalore"
  
}
```

trying to sort with this

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "MDMGlobalData.City": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Got the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [MDMGlobalData.City] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
      }
......
```

Therefore I updated mapping with fielddata enabled

```
PUT my_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "MDMGlobalData": {
      "properties": {
        "City": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I search

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "MDMGlobalData.City": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

And it works